# How to retain the values of select box in jsp after logging out from the page

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am working in a application where i have a select box where i got values from the database.Now i have to select one value that will go to the database,it is going but when i am logging out from the page the the value is not there how to solve this ?? i am getting the selected value back in the jsp page when i am logging into the jsp page. As i am posting my code

```
motivator = existingProfile.get(i).getMotivator();

<th>What would be the single biggest motivator in a potential new opportunity?</th>
                <td>
                    <select id="motivator" name="motivator" multiple="multiple">
                        <% while(rs8.next()){
                            motivatorString = rs8.getString("motivators");

                            System.out.println("motivatorString :"+motivator);
                        %>


                        <option value ="<%=motivatorString %>" ><%=motivatorString %> </option>

                        <%} %>
                    </select>
                </td>
```

this motivator is holding the selected value i want it  selected along with the other values in the select box

Comment: What do you mean by "logging out from the page" ??

Comment: Additionally, you really should avoid using scriptlets and switch to JSTL.

Comment: when i am signing out from the page

Comment: please post the entire jsp page

Comment: @PaulNgom entire page is too long to post i just asked how to retain the value in the select box which i was selecting ,and that motivator is holding the selected value

Comment: when you sign out, your program is supposed to release resources and call a static page. So i do not get you when you say that you want to retain a value in the selectbox. In addition you selectbox is populated from database.

Comment: @PaulNgom but after login i   have the value in motivator string it is populating the value from the database after login that much i have done only i am asking how i will show it selected

Comment: you can use selected="selected" in the option you have selected previously